# How to display all products on my homepage in magento 1.7

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7, shopping-cart

I managed to display new products and product by category with these

> {{block type="catalog/product_new" column_count="6" products_count="3"
>   name="home.catalog.product.new" alias="product_homepage"
>   template="catalog/product/new.phtml"}}
>
> {{block type="catalog/product_list" category_id="10"
>   template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}

But I actually want display entire products in my store regardless their categories, is it possible?

My root category id is 3, so I tried with this line but no luck at all,

> {{block type="catalog/product_list" category_id="3"
>   template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}

Any ideas?

I am using the sample data to test magento, so I have this below in the data,

```
Root Catalog (0) 
    Furniture (7) 
    Electronics (42) 
    Apparel (66)
```

**EDIT:**

home.phtml

```
<?php
/**
 * Magento
 *
 * NOTICE OF LICENSE
 *
 * This source file is subject to the Academic Free License (AFL 3.0)
 * that is bundled with this package in the file LICENSE_AFL.txt.
 * It is also available through the world-wide-web at this URL:
 * http://opensource.org/licenses/afl-3.0.php
 * If you did not receive a copy of the license and are unable to
 * obtain it through the world-wide-web, please send an email
 * to license@magentocommerce.com so we can send you a copy immediately.
 *
 * DISCLAIMER
 *
 * Do not edit or add to this file if you wish to upgrade Magento to newer
 * versions in the future. If you wish to customize Magento for your
 * needs please refer to http://www.magentocommerce.com for more information.
 *
 * @category    design
 * @package     base_default
 * @copyright   Copyright (c) 2012 Magento Inc. (http://www.magentocommerce.com)
 * @license     http://opensource.org/licenses/afl-3.0.php  Academic Free License (AFL 3.0)
 */
?>
There was no Home CMS page configured or found.
```

Comment: read this article it may be helpful for you http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/19173/

Answer (score 1):

You can edit your `home.phtml` file and fetch the products manually

```
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($your_category_id)
->getProductCollection()
->addAttributeToSelect('*')
->addAttributeToFilter(
    'status',
    array('eq' =>'1')
);
```

And for all products you can do this

```
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')
->getProductCollection()
->addAttributeToSelect('*')
->addAttributeToFilter(
    'status',
    array('eq' =>'1')
);
```

Comment: sorry, where can I find `home.phtml`? it seems that magento does not load `home.phtml` by default...

Comment: I found home. but there is nothing in it and magento does not load home.phtml by default - it seems!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a best video tutorial on [how to display products in home page](http://microgiantgroup.com/how-to-show-products-in-home-page-in-magento-1-x-2-x.html)

Comment: A link to a potential solution is always welcome, but please [add context around the link](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8259/169503) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. Take into account that being _barely more than a link to an external site_ is a possible reason as to [Why and how are some answers deleted?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).

Answer (score 1):

1. Step 1: Login into your Magento Admin Dashboard;

   2. Step 2: Go to: CMS -> Pages -> And choose Home Page;
   3. Step 3: Now you must see the some edit options which will be applied for the HomePage.
   4. Step 4: Go to: Contet Tab from left;
   5. Step 5: Add following snippet in the WYSIWYG (As know as “What You See Is What You Get”)

;

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" name="home.catalog.product.list" alias="products_homepage" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}
```